# How to calculate mean absolute percentage error for regression probem in Python?

Tags: performance, keras, regression, mse

I am trying to calculate percentage error of the performance for regression problem. I tried some methods described in other answers but it seems to be not working properly, please let me know if you know/ have used or implemented any code to compute **percentage RMSE** or **mean absolute peprcentage error** in tensorflow-keras.

Comment: Why don't you use the Keras loss `mean_absolute_percentage_error`?

Comment: It gives me tensor object as answer and I am not able to read value from it. So, I thought, if I can define my own function for MAPE, it will be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up calculating MAPE as follow:

```
def mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true, y_pred = np.array(y_true), np.array(y_pred)
    return np.mean(np.abs((y_true - y_pred) / y_true)) * 100
```

and is working properly :)

Answer (score 1):

mape = np.abs((actual - predicted) / actual).mean(axis=0) * 100